# How Long to Rest After Back Spasm

Tags: gym, injury, back-pain, lower-back

It's been three days that I have not hit the gym. I got a back spasm when I was doing squats due to heavy weights. My back is fine now but I feel pain sometimes in left of my lower back above my buttock and I feel a little stiffness in my back.

I am a software developer, so I have to sit for a long time so I am thinking of doing some flexibility training for my back.

I am thinking of hitting the gym starting tomorrow. Will it be a good idea?

Please help me out!
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Ethically, I must recommend that you see a doctor.  Practically, I recommend that you start squatting again (with 50% reduction in work-weight) as soon as sharp pain has dulled, and resume progress carefully from there.  Consider [this back rehab case study](http://startingstrength.com/article/strength-health/back_rehab_a_case_study) (much worse than you've described).

Comment: Sorry, seeking advice on injuries is off topic on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are ready to get back to it. Flexibility training in the gym will probably not be as effective as taking regular breaks from software development to move around. Two things I would encourage you to consider with returning to exercise:

1. Start a little light and monitor the load. Keeping a close eye on how heavy and how frequently you lift are key.
2. Check in on how you feel for 24 hours following. Especially with back injuries, it is important to monitor how much you do and how you feel inside and outside of the gym. Generally, you should be pain free and not getting cramps. 24 hours after exercise, you should have no more pain or tightness than before you started the workout.

I hope this helps :)

Comment: I feel a little sharp pain on below my lower back which reach my thigh too. what concern should i take..

Comment: Sharp pain and restricted movement? I would go to the doctor/ healthcare professional for that.